# OpenCV camera model illustration - why is the image not inverted?

Tags: opencv

I am trying to understand the model described in the page below. Why is the image not inverted and behind the plane XcYc?

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.3/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

Comment: Because the camera captor is in front of the pinhole and not behind (like your eyes if you were thinking of it).

Comment: @T.Lucas Actually the image in our retina is upside down: [Right Side Up - 
Studies of perception show the importance of being upright](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/right-side-up-2008-05/). Most likely the sensor automatically inverts the image. See also this [course](http://cvpr.cecs.anu.edu.au/files/petercorkekioloa2012.pdf).

Comment: See also [Why would the brain flip the images perceived by your eyes?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/337/why-would-the-brain-flip-the-images-perceived-by-your-eyes?newreg=2bea0cc2fd3b4e709bec759c1b984a45)

Comment: @Catree not relevant here, as I said the shown model is with an image plan in front of the pinhole which is equivalent and easier to represent than a model where the image plan is behing, like your eyes. You can draw it to understand.

Comment: @T.Lucas Yes the figure is correct. To answer to the OP interrogation, this is just a more convenient way to represent, that is equivalent mathematically. But in the pinhole camera model, the projected image is inverted. Or in a DSLR, where the "rectification" is done automatically or using a pentaprism to have a correct image in the viewfinder.